# Notify Activity when button clicked in Fragment

Tags: android

I have an Activity:

```kotlin
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        var fragment = WheelFragment.newInstance("a", "b")
        supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.mainFrame, fragment).commit()
}
```

Now in the fragment I wish to notify the activity to about button click and send data.

```kotlin
class WheelFragment : Fragment() {
  
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
       
    }

    override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {

        val view: View = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_wheel, container, false)

        val buttonNextWheel1 = view.findViewById<View>(R.id.buttonNextWheel)
        buttonNextWheel1.setOnClickListener {
            Log.d("DTAG", "Send some data here")
        }
        return view
    }
}
```

Comment: Use LiveData with shared viewmodel or implement interface .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can trigger the function you want to execute inside Activity from Fragment like so:

```
 (activity as MainActivity).doSomeThing()
```

Activity

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    val TAG = "yourTag"
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
    }
    
    
    public fun doSomeThing() {
       Log.i(TAG, "doSomeThing: ")
    }
}
```

Fragment

```
class WheelFragment  : Fragment() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

    }
    override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {

        val view: View = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_wheel, container, false)

        val buttonNextWheel1 = view.findViewById<View>(R.id.buttonNextWheel)
        buttonNextWheel1.setOnClickListener {
            Log.d("DTAG", "Send some data here")
            (activity as MainActivity).doSomeThing()
        }
        return view
    }
}
```